# How to compute simultaneous confidence region of OLS coefficients in statsmodels/python?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I have been searching around but couldn't find a way to compute the confidence ellipsoid for \beta in OLS.
I suppose there is an existing function to call for this instead of coding this up myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`conf_int` method](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.conf_int.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.conf_int) of a `RegressionResults` instance.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.standard_normal((100,3)), columns=["y","x1","x2"])

res = ols("y ~ 1 + x1 + x2", data).fit()
# 90% confidence interval uses an alpha of 1 - 90%
ci = res.conf_int(alpha=0.10)
print(ci)
```

```
                  0         1
Intercept -0.148565  0.173427
x1        -0.195020  0.184610
x2        -0.100552  0.209615
```

You can access the individual elements by variables name, e.g., `ci.loc["Intercept"]`, since these are just pandas `DataFrame`s.

Comment: conf_int only gives confidence intervals of each \beta, not the simultaneous confidence region. Correct?

Comment: There is no support for multivariate confidence regions.  You could, for example, invert the `wald_test` by evaluating on a grid by finding points where the p-value is smaller than 1 minus the confidence level.